# Display last <li> first

Tags: html, html-lists

Is it possible to display the last `<li>` at the start of the list **without** using JavaScript?

For example if I had this code, how would `<li>Bob</li>` be displayed before `<li>James</li>` while keeping the structure below the same?

```
<ul>
<li>James</li>
<li>Chris</li>
<li>Bobby</li>
<li>Bob</li>
</ul>
```

Note: I cannot use JavaScript!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: It's certainly possible in pure CSS, but it would be compatible with far more browsers (at the time of writing) if you simply re-ordered the `<li>` elements on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't manipulate the html (adding id or class attributes for example):

```
ul{display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}/*allows use of the 'order' attribute; allows seperate lines*/
li{width: 100%;}/*puts each list item back on a separate line*/
li:nth-child(1){order:2}/*make the 1st li item the 2nd*/
li:nth-child(2){order:3}
li:nth-child(3){order:4}
li:nth-child(4){order:1}/*make the 4th li item the 1st*/
```

compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox